# What is the tag for [support] questions that seek to document the way the site software works?

Tags: support, tags, questions, meta

Is there an additional tag to place on [support] questions to indicate that they are requesting clarification about how a feature of the site works (in effect, attempting to add a tiny additional piece of site documentation), and not asking how to perform some action, requesting moderator or developer support, etc.

A look through the tag space and wikis did not locate anything obvious.

Comment: There is `faq-proposed` but that should x be used only if you really know what you're doing.

Comment: If there is no such tag it seems worth creating, but [documentation] is already in use for something else.  The purpose would be to signal that it is lower/different priority than "user needs help" (at least for mod, dev, community managers and SE employees, who may be tasked with monitoring MSO support threads), and it can be used to look for the informational questions when searching.  In fact [informational] might be a good way to phrase it.

Comment: @Pëkka: That should only be used if you anticipate the question being common enough to warrant an entry in \[faq\].